# Deriving a diffusion equation from a given mass flux density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, conservation-laws, density, diffusion

I am given that the mass flux density $q$ of a substance in a medium obeys the following physical law.

> $$q=-D\frac{n^3}{n-n_0}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}+nv,$$
>
> where $n(x,t)$ is the concentration of the substance in the medium, $D$ is a constant coefficient of diffusion, $n_0$ is a constant parameter and $v(x,t)$ is the macroscopic velocity of the medium.

I have the following tasks:

> 1. Derive a diffusion equation from the above physical law.
> 2. Consider a steady state when both $n$ and $v$ are independent of $t$, then simplify the diffusion equation in the steady state condition.
> 3. Determine its general solution provided that $n_0=0$, $v(x)=v_0$ and $q=0$.

My initial thought for 1 is to use the conservation of mass equation: $$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=0,$$ but differentiating $q$ does not give a particularly elegant answer.

Some help would be great!

Comment: Why does it have to be particularly elegant?

Answer (score 0):

I think your are simply supposed to state that the diffusion equation is:
$$\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left[nv-D\frac{n^3}{n-n_0}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}\right]=0$$

Then when assuming steady-state in the next question you can simply integrate to get:
$$q\left(x\right)=nv-D\frac{n^3}{n-n_0}\frac{\partial n}{\partial x}=K$$
where $K$ is some constant. I will leave determining the integration constant and getting the general solution for $n$ to you.